# Emacs unable to locate python

Tags: python, emacs, development-environment, eshell, elpy

I am trying enable python dev environment in Doom Emacs (to which I am a newbie); I installed elpy; and tried to launch shell to which it says "python not found but can be installed from Microsoft...".

Then I added this to my config.el:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32")
```

and tried again; displays this in mini-buffer:

```
Python shell interpreter 'C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32' cannot be found. Please set 'python-shell-interpreter' to a valid python binary.
```

But that's where my python binaries reside. I have added the same path to my "exec-path"; still can't run python in eshell.

Comment: I think `python-shell-interpreter` must be the name of the binary itself, not just the directory.  So you probably want `(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe")`

Comment: @0x5453 Nope, still the same problem.

Comment: Is it only eshell that has the problem? Can you run python from a comint shell? from the command line? what is the value of your %PATH%?

Comment: @NickD not in emacs(comint or eshell). However, I am able to run python on command line. ```%PATH% is "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\" and "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\"```

Comment: Presumably, those PATH entries aren't in the PATH when examined from a shell within emacs?  If emacs has the correct PATH, `(executable-find "python")` (or whatever the binary should be on Windows) shouldn't return `nil`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I uninstalled the Python that I had originally used for the `elpy` "rpc" venv, so to fix it, I had to recreate the virual environment, like this:

```
M-x elpy-rpc-reinstall-virtualenv
```